# Change CSS class with JavaScript in sync with Image Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
window.onload = function(){
    setActive()
}

var dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dot")
var slide = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");

function setActive(){
    for (var i = 0; i < slide.length; i++){
        if((slide[i].style.opacity = 0) === 0){
            dots[i].classList.add("active");
        }
        else {
            dots[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 95vh;
    -webkit-background-size: auto;
    -moz-background-size: auto;
    -o-background-size: auto;
    background-size: auto;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0.6), rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1));

}

.slides {
    height: 95vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #252f31;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slide_1 {
    background: red no-repeat center center;
}

.slide_2 {
    background: blue no-repeat center center;
}

.slide_3 {
    background: green no-repeat center center;
}

/* https://codepen.io/vavik96/pen/BRxxQx?editors=1100 */
/* Example of carousel */

.slide {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;

    animation: carousel-fade 15s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: carousel-fade 15s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: carousel-fade 15s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: carousel-fade 15s linear infinite;
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
}

@keyframes carousel-fade {
    0%, 38%, 100% {opacity: 0; }
    10% {opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes carousel-fade {
    0%, 38%, 100% {opacity: 0;}
    10% {opacity: 1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes carousel-fade {
    0%, 38%, 100% {opacity: 0;}
    10% {opacity: 1;}
}

@-ms-keyframes carousel-fade {
    0%, 38%, 100% {opacity: 0;}
    10% {opacity: 1;}
}

.dotContainer {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    right: 17%;
}

.dot {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
    background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Photography Resume</title>
        <meta name="description" content="DESCRIPTION">

        <!-- Roboto Font -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <!-- Slide Show Images -->
        <div class="slides">
            <div class="slide slide_1"></div>
            <div class="slide slide_2"></div>
            <div class="slide slide_3"></div>
        </div> <!-- End Slide Show Images -->

        <div class="dotContainer">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </div>
        
        <!-- JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ive been working on this for awhile now and running into issues. Ive managed (with help from people here!) to knock out most of my issues, though I have another now.

Long story short, I have some dots that I want to change with the rotation of a image carousel on a website that I am practicing making. The images fadein/out on a 5sec delay over 15 seconds. They are set as background images and faded using CSS animations.

Ive written logic which I thought would work in JavaScript, but I believe because the animation does not physically change the Opacity to 1 (still hard coded at 0), its not working. I cant think of another option and google isnt helping me out right now either.

Im looking to see if there is a way to write the code that I can work this out with my current setup.

The other thing I was thinking about trying, but not had a chance yet (going to sleep and just want to feel things out) is that maybe I could animate the active class using the same methods I did for the opacity. Something I still will look into tomorrow maybe.

tl;dr: I need to find a way to make my active class cycle through the "Dots" at the same speed as my CSS cycles through my images. (basically every 5 secs or so)

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example if you want us to help

Comment: updated the code to remove the extraneous.

Comment: can you add the code that makes the slides work. Or you just want to active the dots in a loop every 5 seconds, regardles of the slides?

Comment: Sorry, the slides did work, just the images were on my computer so it was displaying black. I changed them to a color to show the transition. 

The three dots in the lower right is what I am trying to control. I am trying to make them darker to keep in line with the images. Basically, slide_1 top dot = black (all rest grey). Slide_2 middle dot is black (other two grey) etc.

Though I am trying to do it without changing the way the images are animated which is currently done through CSS only. I know its possible to do it ALL with JavaScript, just trying to sync images and dots as current.

Comment: Ok. I see what you want to do. Ther problem is you wont be able to control the slidess with the dots if you do it all in css. Would you lik me to fix it. So have a 5second out slide but controlling it with the dots

Comment: I would be interested to see what you can do for sure. Ive been racking my head around it for a few days now (plus about 3 or 4 different iterations of my header there).

Comment: well, lets see what i can craft jajaja